# How comes the basic block does not have terminator?

Tags: if-statement, llvm, code-generation

So I am trying to generate code for an if statement but I am receiving "Basic Block in function (function_name) does not have terminator!
label %then"

But if check the code generated it seems like the terminators are there for each block.

```
define void @M4_Main_main() {
%1 = call i8* @__lcpl_new(%struct.__lcpl_rtti* @RString)
%2 = bitcast i8* %1 to %struct.TString*
%3 = getelementptr %struct.TString, %struct.TString* %2, i32 0, i32 1
store i32 22, i32* %3
%4 = getelementptr %struct.TString, %struct.TString* %2, i32 0, i32 2
store i8* getelementptr inbounds ([23 x i8], [23 x i8]* @0, i32 0, i32 0), i8** %4
%5 = call i8* @__lcpl_new(%struct.__lcpl_rtti* @RIO)
%6 = bitcast i8* %5 to %struct.TIO*
%7 = call %struct.TIO* @M2_IO_out(%struct.TIO* %6, %struct.TString* %2)
br i1 true, label %then, label %else

then:                                             ; preds = %0
                                              ; No predecessors!
%9 = call i8* @__lcpl_new(%struct.__lcpl_rtti* @RString)
%10 = bitcast i8* %9 to %struct.TString*
%11 = getelementptr %struct.TString, %struct.TString* %10, i32 0, i32 1
store i32 12, i32* %11
%12 = getelementptr %struct.TString, %struct.TString* %10, i32 0, i32 2
store i8* getelementptr inbounds ([13 x i8], [13 x i8]* @1, i32 0, i32 0), i8** %12
%13 = call i8* @__lcpl_new(%struct.__lcpl_rtti* @RIO)
%14 = bitcast i8* %13 to %struct.TIO*
%15 = call %struct.TIO* @M2_IO_out(%struct.TIO* %14, %struct.TString* %10)
br label %ifcont

else:                                             ; preds = %0
                                              ; No predecessors!
br label %ifcont

ifcont:                                           ; preds = %16, %8
%iftmp = phi i32 [ <null operand!>, %8 ], [ <null operand!>, %16 ]
%17 = call i8* @__lcpl_new(%struct.__lcpl_rtti* @RString)
%18 = bitcast i8* %17 to %struct.TString*
%19 = getelementptr %struct.TString, %struct.TString* %18, i32 0, i32 1
store i32 22, i32* %19
%20 = getelementptr %struct.TString, %struct.TString* %18, i32 0, i32 2
store i8* getelementptr inbounds ([23 x i8], [23 x i8]* @2, i32 0, i32 0), i8** %20
%21 = call i8* @__lcpl_new(%struct.__lcpl_rtti* @RIO)
%22 = bitcast i8* %21 to %struct.TIO*
%23 = call %struct.TIO* @M2_IO_out(%struct.TIO* %22, %struct.TString* %18)
br i1 false, label %then1, label %else2

then1:                                            ; preds = %ifcont
                                              ; No predecessors!
br label %ifcont3

else2:                                            ; preds = %ifcont
                                              ; No predecessors!
%26 = call i8* @__lcpl_new(%struct.__lcpl_rtti* @RString)
%27 = bitcast i8* %26 to %struct.TString*
%28 = getelementptr %struct.TString, %struct.TString* %27, i32 0, i32 1
store i32 12, i32* %28
%29 = getelementptr %struct.TString, %struct.TString* %27, i32 0, i32 2
store i8* getelementptr inbounds ([13 x i8], [13 x i8]* @3, i32 0, i32 0), i8** %29
%30 = call i8* @__lcpl_new(%struct.__lcpl_rtti* @RIO)
%31 = bitcast i8* %30 to %struct.TIO*
%32 = call %struct.TIO* @M2_IO_out(%struct.TIO* %31, %struct.TString* %27)
br label %ifcont3

ifcont3:                                          ; preds = %25, %24
%iftmp4 = phi i32 [ <null operand!>, %24 ], [ <null operand!>, %25 ]
%33 = call i8* @__lcpl_new(%struct.__lcpl_rtti* @RString)
%34 = bitcast i8* %33 to %struct.TString*
%35 = getelementptr %struct.TString, %struct.TString* %34, i32 0, i32 1
store i32 4, i32* %35
%36 = getelementptr %struct.TString, %struct.TString* %34, i32 0, i32 2
store i8* getelementptr inbounds ([5 x i8], [5 x i8]* @4, i32 0, i32 0), i8** %36
%37 = call i8* @__lcpl_new(%struct.__lcpl_rtti* @RIO)
%38 = bitcast i8* %37 to %struct.TIO*
%39 = call %struct.TIO* @M2_IO_out(%struct.TIO* %38, %struct.TString* %34)
ret void
}
```

I read that to terminate a block it should have either a return or a branch and all my blocks do have such a statement. What could be the problem here ?

Comment: What version are you compiling the llvm with?

Comment: Please provide a full file that can reproduce your issue (with opt for instance)

Comment: Your IR looks strange. It seems that there are unnamed BB with no predecessors (as the comments suggest). This holds also for your then block which might be empty because all instructions are in the following BB.